# How do you write accented characters in a foreign language?

Tags: fonts, formatting

I'm trying to include the titles of TED talks that I'm translated into my resume, but since the talks are in Spanish there are some characters that don't show up correctly.

When I write:

```
\item (Spanish into English){De que el futuro de la educación está a tan sólo un clic}
```

the text shows up as

```
De que el futuro de la educacin est a tan slo un clic
```

and simply doesn't show the special characters.

How do I get Latex to display special characters in Spanish or Portuguese?

Comment: It's unfortunate that XeTeX isn't mentioned on that question.

Comment: @SeanAllred I give both pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX solutions in my answer.

Comment: @AlanMunn Whoops – I'm not sure how I didn't see that :)